# AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'render' In Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, pygame, attributeerror

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oVZ-VBaC2E&t=1264s) and I got an error

```
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'render'
```

I have only just started using Python so I do not know how to fix it. Does anyone have any ideas?
The code was as follows

```
import pygame
import config
from player import Player
from game_state import GameState

class Game:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.objects = []
        self.game_State = GameState.NONE

    def set_up(self):
        player = Player(1, 1)
        self.objects.append(player)
        print("do set up")
        self.game_state = GameState.RUNNING

    def update(self):
        self.screen.fill(config.BLACK)
        print("update")
        self.handle_events()

        for object in self.objects:
            object.render(self.screen)
```

Comment: The error message says, that the class `Player` has no instance method `render`. You have to implement the method.

Comment: https://youtu.be/6oVZ-VBaC2E?t=613

At that point they define the render method in the player class  you must have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The example video includes a section on defining the Player class which includes the render method.  You must have missed this while typing in the code from the video.